# Use LabelMe Dataset to create tf.data for image segmentation

Tags: label, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

So I want to try to use this tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation

As a base for my own project. Using custom data of course.

So to get data suitable for semantic segmentation I found the LabelMe Tool:

https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme

The tool works create, however, I cant seem to be able to convert the output into the same tf.datasets format used in the linked tutorial. Can anyone point me towards the right solution to do this?